# Twilio message method 'getDetailedDeliveryReceipts' is returning an empty array

Tags: reactjs, twilio, chat, message

We are trying to show status of the message like read, delivered, undelivered etc in twilio/conversation, but getDetailedDeliveryReceipts method is showing messageStatus = [] not returning any properties like status etc. What am I missing here ?

const messageStatus = await message.getDetailedDeliveryReceipts();

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Delivery Receipts docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/delivery-receipts-overview) the Delivery Receipts is only for non-Chat Participants.

Seems that to do what you want you have to follow [the Read Horizon docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/read-horizon-overview), specifically looking at:

```
// get last read message index of your participant in the conversation
conversation.lastReadMessageIndex();

// get last read message index of another participant in the conversation
participant.lastReadMessageIndex();
```

You need to assume that if the message is in the conversation that you have a delivered message and then you need to loop through all the participants and check the `lastReadMessageIndex` of each to determine how you want to mark the message as read.